# Reversing a string without creating extra memory

Tags: c#

I have a string which is of about 1mb size. The requirement is to reverse the string without allocating another temp string of size 1 MB. I tried the following code

```
string name = "abcde";

string target = "";
for(int i = name.Length - 1; i >=0; i--)
{
    target += name[i];
    name = name.Remove(i);                
    int n = name.Length;
}
```

but my friend says  if we use the function `name.Remove(i)` it will return a new string but it is not guaranteed that the old string will be deleted from memory and so there is no guarantee that the size will be reduced. is it true? if so is there any other option available to reverse a string without allocating extra memory?

Comment: You could try writing it out to a file in reverse order then reading it back in :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: nice idea, what will happen to the original string? can we guarantee its deletion

Comment: Why the criteria of reversing without allowing extra memory? The garbage collector is pretty good at its job.

Comment: Every time you do a name = name.Remove(i), another string gets created minus the character (as per my understanding of immutable objects). So, if that's true, you are creating a lot of string in order to achieve this.

Comment: Is it viable for you to use a `IList<Char>` instead of a string? Then you could reverse it without allocating new memory.

Comment: NO NO NO - please don't take that suggestion of mine seriously. It's a horrible way to do it.

Comment: I guess there is no possible way of doing it except not allocating more memory. Reverse method is already provided for strings by MS, use that. You can possibly use StringBuilder.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Wouldn't that be too cumbersome, knowing that the string is 1 MB, it got to be huge?

Comment: Please be aware that simply reversing an array is no effective solution since this wont take into consideration surrogates and unicode mark codepoints which might lead to invalid or even broken strings

Comment: @Shaks: If the string is 1MB, the `List<Char>` or `Char[]` would also be 1MB, so that would be no difference. But it would be easier to manipulate without intervention of the string intern pool and immutability problems. **Edit** But i haven't considered what Polity has mentioned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your string "abcde" is a constant in memory. You can't change it, as it is immutable. What you want is to create a new string, and for this you need new memory.

Answer (score 6):

use `StringBuilder` you can manupulate with char array, but not with `string`, bacause it's immutable

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, and you can't reverse it without allocating new memory

[String from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be
>   changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it
>   appear as if you can do this.

From the same link see this example:

```
string b = "h";
b += "ello";
```

and the explanation.

> when you write this code, the compiler actually creates a new string
>   object to hold the new sequence of characters, and that new object is
>   assigned to b. The string "h" is then eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Is it possible to reverse it with less memory than the original string?

Comment: @Jeeva, when you will reverse the string, your previous string will be eligible for garbage collection, you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

String are Immutables. When you declare it you can't change it. So whatever you try, will create and use new memory.

```
string name = "aaaaa":
name = name.Remove(0); // this is allocating new memory.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Note how I don't bother to use a variable?
        //This is a nasty hack that knows the compiler will intern the value.
        //One of the many downsides of hacking the BCL.
        while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Console.ReadLine()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("he\0llo");  
            "he\0llo".ReverseInPlace();
        }
    }
}

public static class Helper
{
    //Does not support multi-char values.
    public static unsafe void ReverseInPlace(this string str)
    {
        fixed (char* pfixed = str)
            for (int i = 0, ii = str.Length - 1; i < str.Length / 2; i++, ii--)
            {
                var p1 = (char*)pfixed + i;
                var p2 = (char*)pfixed + ii;
                var temp = *p1;
                *p1 = *p2;
                *p2 = temp;
            }
    }
}
```

If you use this, you will likely die... or something.  Heck, I don't even know how to write unsafe code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some control over the original data, you should be able to do this. E.g. if you can demand a `char[]` without ever creating a `string`, you can reverse it in place.

For example, in *your* example, you could have `var name = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}` instead of a string, and then reverse that in place.

(Obviously you can't do this for a 1MB string, but wherever you're getting your string from, if you can initially load it as a `char[]` instead...)

If you can only have a `string`, you're out of luck. They are immutable - you can only modify a string by copying it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder is Mutable and should give you the best possible efficiency in this case

```
string inpuStr = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog...blah blah blah up to 1MB";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = inpuStr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                builder.Append(inpuStr[i]); 
            }
           return builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Completely lost the plot, been using C++ too much recently I forgot C# strings are immutable.

In short, you have to allocate new memory to alter a string in C#. You can do this in the most straightforward way by doing something like this:

```
string ReverseString(string value)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        char[] newBuffer = new char[value.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            newBuffer[newBuffer.Length - i - 1] = value[i];
        value = new string(newBuffer);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? aren't string immutables?

Comment: Yeah, dunno what the hell I was thinking. Been using too much C++ lately it seems.

Comment: Strings are immutable, name[0] = 'e' does not compile.

Comment: Lol I understood the first few downvotes when there was incorrect information in my answer, but now this is getting a bit stupid, considering the information is correct, and there is a working example here.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try with linq to reverse

    string original = "abcde";
    string reverseValue = new string(original.Reverse().ToArray());

you can try also with 

string result= new string(original.Select((c, index) => new { c, index })
                                         .OrderByDescending(x => x.index)
                                         .ToArray());
```

Comment: How is that not creating new Memory?

Comment: @MBen if you initialize a local variable you store your value in the stack

Answer (score 0):

Practically there is no correct way for reversing a string without at least allocating the same amount of memory as is occupied by the string you want to reverse. (Theoretically its possible to reverse a string in memory but this is so dis recommended, i'm not even going to enter that area). Now as for reversing the string itself. I'm working on a little project called StringExtensions in which i try to hammer down all the gotchas that can occur when working with strings. One of the biggest gotchas is working with the UTF-16 encoding which is used extensively throughout the framework. My implementation of reversing a string looks something like this:

```
    static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetTextElementSegments(string value)
    {
        int[] elementOffsets = StringInfo.ParseCombiningCharacters(value);

        int lastOffset = -1;
        foreach (int offset in elementOffsets)
        {
            if (lastOffset != -1)
            {
                int elementLength = offset - lastOffset;
                Tuple<int, int> segment = new Tuple<int,int>(lastOffset, elementLength);
                yield return segment;
            }

            lastOffset = offset;
        }

        if (lastOffset != -1)
        {
            int lastSegmentLength = value.Length - lastOffset;

            Tuple<int, int> segment = new Tuple<int, int>(lastOffset, lastSegmentLength);
            yield return segment;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "t\u0301e\u0302s\u0303t\u0304";
        StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder(input.Length);

        var segments = GetTextElementSegments(input);

        foreach (var segment in segments.Reverse())
        {
            resultBuilder.Append(input, segment.Item1, segment.Item2);
        }

        Debug.Assert(resultBuilder.ToString() == "t\u0304s\u0303e\u0302t\u0301s");
    }
```

Note that this takes care of surrogate pairs, unicode mark codepoints and only allocates memory similar to the amount occupied by the input string itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really serious about no additional allocations, you need to `fix` the string and use `unsafe` pointer code. Or, perhaps, get a reference to the internal `char[]` using reflection.

You really don't want to do this. Really. I mean, **really**. Please, don't do this except as a learning exercise. If people find code like that in production they're likely to come looking for you with a weapon.

I'm not going to attempt writing such code (as I know I'll get it wrong). But here are some links which would get you started:

- [Strings Undocumented](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3377/Strings-UNDOCUMENTED) - A quite old article, but has the best examples.
- [John Skeet on Strings](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx) - A bit high level for what you want, but a good place to 
  start.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a Java solution for this by using the toCharArray() function of Strings and XOR operations to swap characters:

```
public static String reverseString(String str) {
    return reverseStringXor(str.toCharArray(), 0, str.length() - 1);
}

private static String reverseStringXor(char[] str, int start, int end) {
    while (start < end) {
        str[start] ^= str[end];
        str[end] ^= str[start];
        str[start] ^= str[end];
        start++;
        end--;
    }
    return String.valueOf(str);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help

```
string reverse = new string("ABCDEFGHI".ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: This will still use extra memory.

Answer (score -2):

This is one of your answer.

```
 for (int i = textBox1.TextLength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
 {
    textBox1.Text += textBox1.Text[i];
 }
 textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(0, textBox1.Text.Length / 2);
```